# make sense of a c define macro?

Tags: c, macros, bitwise-operators

I am new to c development.
I am trying to understand a snippet of code related to a midi application:

```
#define GETCMD(p) ((p.data.midi.h& 0x70)>>4)
#define GETCH(p) ((p.data.midi.h& 0x0F)+1)
```

I presume the above are 2 macros.
What is not really clear are the hex values 0x70 and 0x0F.
In the first line from my understanding it is a right shift of 4 on the h pointer?

The following makes less sense

```
#define SETCMD_CH(p, c1, c2) p.data.midi.h=0x80|(c2-1)|((c1&7)<<4)
```

Can please anyone let me understand these 3 defines?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hex values `0x70` and `0x0F` is a bitmasks `01110000` and `00001111`

Comment: The "&" is bitwise-and; there are no pointers in this code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GETCMD` extracts 3 command bits (from bits 4..6) and returns them as a value in the range 0..7.

`GETCH` returns 4 channel bits (from bits 0..3) and returns them as a value in the range 1..16.

`SETCMD_CH` sets the above command and channel bits, i.e. it's just the reverse operation of the above two macros combined.

This bitwise operations are just the required shifts and masks to get/set the appropriate bits within `p.data.midi.h`. You might want to read up on bitwise operations if it's not clear to you how these work.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look of the structure of "p.data.midi.h"

Which data type do you have, especially in the .h?

I think that is a bitwise operation between the data you have *.data.midi.h and 0x70 (DEC = 112; BIN = 0111 0000) and then a shift right of 4 as you guess.

Suppose you have in the *.data.midi.h data the value in Binary 0101 0000 after the GETCMD you'll have 101.

In this way you have discovered which bits are to value 1 in your data. (2 Nibble)

GETCH is working on first nibble (0x0F = Bin 0000 1111) then adding 1 for some reason which I don't know.

SETCMD_CH seams to set some bits of the *.data.midi.h that you can pass in the c1, c2 params.
*.data.midi.h =0x80|(c2-1)|((c1&7)<<4)
*.data.midi.h = 1000 0000 | (c2-1) | ((c1 & 0000 0111) << 4)

With the c1 I'm quite sure you can set one of the "commands".

I think you must think in binary in this case to solve and understand.

Sorry for my solution to your problem that maybe cause to you even more confusion :).